# REST API POST: passing foreign key in url vs json body

Tags: rest, api-design

Let's say I have two objects: `Student` and `Homework`. `Homework` has `Student` as fk:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE homework (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    topic varchar(255),
    student_id int REFERENCES student(id)
)
```

Is there any convention for what is the right way to structure the API endpoints for CRUD?
If I want to create a new homework for a student, I could send a json body with student id

```
{
    "student_id": 1,
    "topic": "topic
}
```

to `POST https://website.com/api/v1/homework`.

Or I could send

```
{
    "topic": "topic
}
```

to `POST https://website.com/api/v1/students/{student_id}/homework` and take student id from URL.

In second case I would be sending a POST request with incomplete fields and in first case I would have one extra endpoint (since I would need `/students/{id}/homework` anyway to fetch particular student's homework.)

Comment: I write client code for an API that uses the second approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two entities `Student` and `Homework`. A `Homework` entity belongs to `Student`.

So the more semantically correct approach would be:

- Create Homework Endpoint:

  ```
  POST https://website.com/api/v1/students/{student_id}/homeworks
  ```
- Delete Homework EndPoint:

  ```
  DELETE https://website.com/api/v1/homeworks/{homework_id}
  ```

---

### There are **no** agreed rules but this is generally a widely followed pattern:

If `A` owns `B`, and you want to create a new `B` entity, your path will be like `/A/{A_Id}/B`.

- Boilerplate Request:

  ```
  POST /ParentEntity/ParentId/ChildEntity
  ```

Now `B` was created and you have an `id` associated with it, so you can directly alter `B` (say for any mutation operation, `POST`, `DELETE`, `PUT`, `PATCH`).

```
DELETE /B/{id}

PUT /B{id}
```

OR

```
POST /B/{id}/delete

POST /B/{id}/update
```

(this one is followed in [StackOverflow Docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), where your request intention/action is defined in URL suffix instead of being defined by your HTTP method)

---

### Why do we do directly alter B? Why not do something like:

```
DELETE /A/{Aid}/B/{Bid}
```

Because `/A/{Aid}` would be redundant information. Since it is guaranteed that `{Bid}` would always be unique even though multiple `B` entities can belong to a single `A` entity.

---

### Additional References:

You can see the API pattern Stackoverflow has used for their APIs here for any future reference. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=category#docs

Comment: Adding `/delete` to your URI for a `DELETE` request is _definitely not_ a widely accepted pattern.

Comment: @Evert yep overlooked that. I initially had `POST` for both delete and update. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, what's the point for using `POST .../homework/add` instead of just `POST .../homework`?

Comment: It should have been `homeworks` instead of `homework`. My bad. In that case, you will have `{parent}/{parentId}/homeworks/add` and `{parent}/{parentId}/homeworks`.
When you use POST for everything, your endpoint suffix tells you the intention in a sense, and if you are doing that  then `{parent}/{parentId}/homeworks` would be a GET request that returns a JSON of homeworks on that parentId.